Vuex не видит модули
Vuex store не видит подключенный модуль. Обычно работаю с vue-cli, там все прекрасно работает. А сейчас через vite (может эта информация как-то поможет)
store/index.js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

import { subzonesModule } from '@/store/subzonesModule'

export default createStore({
    modules: {
        subzones: subzonesModule,
    }
})

store/subzonesModule.js
export const subzonesModule = {
    namespaced: true,

    state:() => ({
        cloud_files: '123'
    }),
}



Вы где-то вызываете инициализированный стейт? Без точки вызова у вас будет пустой глобальный стейт (не уверен что это относится к vuex, сейчас из под коробки pinia стоит, а vuex остался за vue2).
